# JAXB XPATH Element always empty

Tags: xpath, jaxb, moxy

I've read a lot of exapmles, and also googled way to much - but still hasn't found the problem.

I'm wondering why my "name" - element is always empty, see result:

```
Category [id=1, name=
        , active=1]
```

My xml-File:

```
<category>
<id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
<active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
<name>
    <language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.somelinkhere.com/languages/1"><![CDATA[bla]]>/language>
</name>
</category>
```

my Java-Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Category {
            private String id;
            private String active;

            @XmlPath("name/language[@id='1']/text()")
            private String name;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
                    @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "PrestaCategory [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", active="
                        + active + "]";
            }...
```

I think it's a small meistake, but I can't find it...

Comment: It's probably only a typo but your XML document is malformed. It should be `</language>` instead of `/language>`.

Comment: It was only a copy+paste error, the original file is not affected. But thank you for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty obvoious - it was necessary to create a jaxb.properties file within the package with this property:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

after that it worked properly....